# What's the difference between <% code %> and <%= code %> in Rails erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

There seems to be a difference between the two, Though I can't tell what exactly.

```
<% code %>
```

And

```
<%= code %>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`<% %>` will evaluate the ruby code contained

`<%= %>` will evaluate and render the code contained

So a template containing:

```
Hello <% user.name %> how are you?
```

...would output:

```
Hello  how are you
```

...whilst...

```
Hello <%= user.name %> how are you?
```

...would output:

```
Hello fred how are you
```

`<% %>` is commonly used for iterators

```
<ul>
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <li><%= user.name %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Finally found it, took me 10 seconds to know what's this doing, but took me 1 hours to find this answer. because of symbol search. btw, Do you know where is the rails official documentation about this symbols?

Answer (score 2):

The `<%` and `%>` only evaluates the ruby code between them, while `<%=` and `%>` outputs the result of evaluation. Don't mix up though

This will output "foo" to the access log and `nil` to the browser output

```
<%= puts "foo" %>
```

while

```
<%= "foo" %>
```

will output "foo" string to the browser.

Comment: you missed a `=` in the first statement. `<% puts "foo" %>` will not output `nil` to browser. It will output `foo` in the server console and log though. `<%= puts "foo" %>` is what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

`<%=  %>` prints the return value of code statement into the browser and `<% %>` just executes the code.