# What is the difference between <%= and the "puts" command in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a segment of code:

```
<% @public_address.each do |key| %>
    <%= key["address"]["address"] %>
<% end %>
```

This displays the keys properly, but this code

```
<% @public_address.each do |key| %>
    <% puts key["address"]["address"] %>
<% end %>
```

displays nothing. What gives? What's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<% %>` and `<%= %>` are used in erb to execute ruby code when rendering a template.

Erb is the default template engine in rails.

### Difference between <% %> and <%= %>

1. `<% %>` Will evaluate the ruby code it contains, but "silently".
   Meaning that no output is going to be printed on the rendered page.
2. `<%= %>` on the other end, evaluates the ruby it contains and
   renders the result on the rendered page.

[What's the difference between <% code %> and <%= code %> in Rails erb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361401/whats-the-difference-between-code-and-code-in-rails-erb)

### What's puts?

Puts is simply a method from Ruby that is used to print a string at runtime. It has nothing to do with erb templates.

Answer (score 0):

In your first bit of code `<%= key["address"]["address"] %>`, the `<%= %>` is rails syntax for evaluating the code inside and returning the value.

In your second bit of code `<% puts key["address"]["address"] %>`, you use `<% %>`, which doesn't return an evaluated rails statement. Furthermore, puts is a method that outputs whatever follows it to the stout object. In a command line program, that means printing out to the terminal screen, but in a web app you aren't working with a terminal screen. You are working with controllers and view templates, so it is necessary to use the evaluative `<%= %>` if you want to return values that will be displayed in the view.